# Lady Chatterlay's Lover: "last crow"

Tags: meaning, idioms

I don't want to be vulgar here. But what does "crow" mean in their conversation:

> Connie:  Then why are you so bitter?
>
> Mellors: I'm not! If my cock gives its last crow, I don't mind!

When they talk about the extermination of mankind?

Comment: This is general reference. A [crow](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/crow--2) is the cry of the rooster (‘cock-a-doodle-doo’). “If my rooster gives its last cry” is what the sentence means.

Comment: And it's _Chatterley_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a pun on *cock*, which can mean the male organ as well as a male chicken.

Mellors is using *crow* to mean ejaculation (just as a cockerel's crowing might be called an ejaculation — see [ODO sense 2](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ejaculation)).

Comment: Such a neat pun.